# How to revoke existing R package on CRAN

Tags: r, cran

I am an R package maintainer. I found some problems in my package and am revising it. Is there some way to revoke or archive my package temporarily until I finish? I don't want people to use it and run into problems.

I read CRAN [Repository Policy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html) but couldn't find anything about revoking packages.

Comment: You can email CRAN and explain the situation and ask them to _archive_ the package for you.  The package page will become minimal and show that the package archived and why.  The package will no longer be available via `install.packages()` etc.  Due to FOSS licenses, which give the users rights such as packages not being removed, you cannot really have a package removed.  This is one of nice features of CRAN (compared to say random GitHub repositories where things can come and go at random).

Comment: Another alternative is to submit a new version with shim/fake functions that produce informative errors.  Which is better, I don't know.  Also, in both cases, you need to consider reverse dependencies if other packages depend on your package.